# Não consigo atualizar informações no banco

Tags: django

Eu recebo de um formulário as seguintes informações, número(que deve ser reservado), reservado_por e telefone. Tenho que pegar o número a reservar e atualizar ele com as informações recebidas, mas da erro.
Quando tento reservar um numero que ainda não está cadastrado no banco, funciona corretamente.

Quando tento atualizar um registro existente no banco ocorre erro e não funciona, mas quando é um novo registro único funciona corretamente, podem me ajudar?

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Numero(models.Model):
situacao = (
    ("D", "Disponivel"),
    ("R", "Reservado"),
    ("P", "Pago")
)

numero = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
reservado_por = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
telefone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
criado_em = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=situacao, null=False, blank=False)


class Meta:
    verbose_name = "número"
    verbose_name_plural = "números"


def __str__(self):
    return self.numero
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from apps.numeros.models import Numero

class NumeroForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Numero
        fields = ('reservado_por', 'telefone', 'numero')
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from apps.numeros.models import Numero
from apps.rifas.models import Rifa
from .forms import NumeroForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

def reservar(request):


if request.method == 'POST':
    form = NumeroForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        numero = form.save(commit=False)
        numero.status = 'R'
        numero.reservado_por = form.cleaned_data['reservado_por']
        numero.telefone = form.cleaned_data['telefone']
        numero.save()
        reverse_lazy('home')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import home, numero, rifa, reservar

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home, name='home'),
    path('numero/', numero, name='numero'),
    path('rifa/', rifa, name='rifa'),
    path('reservar/', reservar, name='reservar_numero'),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agradeço a ajuda, mas consegui resolver o problema assim(ver códigos). Como eu posso receber 1 ou 999 números do modal(cada número é separado por uma vírgula), além do nome e telefone.

Se houver sugestão de melhoria, aceito \õ

Houve alteração apenas na views.py.

**views.py**

```
def reservar(request):
    numeros = request.POST['numero']
    num = numeros.split(",")
    for n in num:
        num = Numero.objects.get(numero=n)
        num.reservado_por = request.POST['reservado_por']
        num.telefone = request.POST['telefone']
        num.status = 'R'
        num.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ola.

Uma ideia é recuperar os valores em uma pagina... update.html

Eu criaria uma função que pegaria por id

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def updateReservar(request,reservar_id):

   reservar =   NumeroForm.objects.get(id=reservar_id)
   formularioReservar = NumeroForm(request.POST)
   if formularioReserva.is_valid():
    preparar = formulario.data
    ...... 
    # codigo para salvar as informações recuperadas
  return render(request, "updateReservar.html", {'reservar': reservar})
```

no urls.py

```
path('reservaID/<reservar_id>', views.updateReservar, name='reservaID')
```

ou

```
 path('update/<int:id>',views.updateReservar,name = "update")
```

html update:

```
{{reservar.reservar}}
```

Na url no navegador seria assim

localhost:8000/reservaID/1

localhost:8000/reservaID/2

localhost:8000/reservaID/3

recupera os valores e ao aparecer no campo edita,no is_valid() adiciona um save para salvar as informações modificada.

seu model esta com o mesmo nome do Forms.

NumeroForm model

NumeroForm forms

a minha escrita do código pode parecer diferente mas a ideia é a mesma